# Is it possible to override the CSS of base Lightning web components like "Highlight Panel"

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I'm trying to figure out a way to change the CSS of LWCs that Salesforce provides in the Lightning App Builder, specifically the "Highlight Panel" but I'm unable to figure out how exactly to do that. I've tried to use a hack where you override the CSS with an invisible web component. I also looked at the new Style Hooks, but I think those are only for buttons and such that you'll add to custom web components. We're trying to change the style of buttons to match the style of buttons elsewhere.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I just found this by accident - maybe it's helpful: https://getoncrm.com/how-to-override-css-of-inner-elements-of-lightning-web-component/

Answer (score 2):

It's not really possible to override the css from standard component. Sometimes you can make small adjustments using the css variables that salesforce provides but that's about it.

I think the only solution is to make your own version with your own css. You might be able to borrow some code from a salesforce repository like https://github.com/salesforce/base-components-recipes though.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this:
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.globalcss}"/>

if you default your app to always open in any custom component, standard ones will inherit the styles

Comment: One shouldn't use this method, because it was never an intended use case. As the technology matures, it will become harder (and probably eventually impossible) to override standard CSS.

Comment: `<ltng:require>` is only avaliable for aura components, not fow LWCs